# How to have my code go down a list of commands that operates a Computer Numerical Control machine

Tags: c++, command-line

I'm new to C++ and I have this project that I have to create a code that understands a list of commands listed in a file. My code opens the file successfully but I'm not sure if it is following the commands.

I've pieced this code but I'm not sure if my command interpuration is wrong or if my output is messed up. I keep getting a line of "cuts" instead of a design.

the prompt is as follows:

A CNC (Computer Numerical Control) machine is used to create metal signage by using a laser cutting tool.

The laser is in one of two states, on or off.

When the laser is on it is cutting metal and making the required sign as it moves.

When the laser is off, the laser moves about freely without cutting anything on the piece of metal.

For this assignment, you will write a C++ program to control the movement of a CNC machine and simulate what it would cut into a metal rectangle.

- You will simulate the metal rectangle by creating an m x n array, initialized to 0s.
- The number of maximum number of rows in the array is 10 and the maximum number of columns is 50.
- The commands to manipulate the laser will be loaded from a file named laser.txt and are as follows:

Table 1: List of commands and their meaning.

```
Command Meaning
I In (move the laser inward so that it begins cutting)
O Out (move the laser outward so that it stops cutting)
R Turn right
L Turn left
A n Move ahead n spaces, n is a positive int <= 80
```

- The laser.txt file will contain one command per line.
- The laser begins in location (0,0) which is in the upper-left corner of the grid.
- The positive x direction is to the right and the positive y direction is down (see the diagram on the next page).
- The laser begins pointing in the positive x direction.
- If the laser is ever at or moves across a location while it is in the “In” position, it marks that location (which can
  be simulated by writing a 1 to your m x n array.)
- When your program is finished simulating the laser’s movement, it should print out the image that would be cut into the metal grid, using spaces for uncut locations and asterisks for cut locations.

Example (user input is underlined for clarity, underlined text in your program is not needed):

```
Enter the file name: laser.txt
Generated grid:
* * * * *
        *
        *
        *
        *


        *
```

Here, the laser.txt contained the following:

```
I
A 4
R
A 4
O
A 2
I
```

If there is any invalid command not listed in Table 1, the program must immediately stop with the following
error message: "Encountered an Invalid command. Terminating."

Finally, if the file name that is given cannot be opened, print the following error message: "Error, cannot open file."

Your program should contain multiple functions that solve smaller pieces of the problem.

Grid Basics

Below is the graphics grid

```
x- axis (+)
y
a
x
i
s
+
(0,0)
```

This is a graphics window. Note the (0,0) is the top left-hand corner and the values of y are positive going down and the x values are positive going in the right direction.

You may assume the laser starts in position (0,0) and is facing east according to the compass rose below.

Note: You must make sure the laser stays in the drawing area at all times.

The above is a representative grid of the CNC’s two-dimensional world with m=16 and n=16.

T represents the initial position of the Laser.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, x = 0, y = 0;
    bool cutting = false;
    const int gridWidth = 80, gridHeight = 50;
    char grid[gridHeight][gridWidth] = {' '};
    char command;

    string fileName; // obtaining and openning file
    cout << "Enter the file name: ";
    cin >> fileName;

    ifstream file(fileName);
    if (!file) {
        cout << "Error, cannot open file." << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    while (file >> command) { // using true/false to operate cutting and positioning
        if (command == 'I') {
            cutting = true;
        }
        else if (command == 'O') {
            cutting = false;
        }
        else if (command == 'R') {
            if (x < gridWidth - 1) x++;
        }
        else if (command == 'L') {
            if (x > 0) x--;
        }
        else if (command == 'A') {
            file >> n;
            if (n > 0 && n <= gridWidth - x) {
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    if (cutting) {
                        grid[y][x+i] = '#';
                    }
                }
                x += n;
            }
        }
    }

    file.close();

    for (int i = 0; i < gridHeight; i++) { // printing grid
        for (int j = 0; j < gridWidth; j++) {
            cout << grid[i][j];
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour] and read about [ask]. Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: It's your interpretation that is wrong. The laser has a **direction of travel**. So `R` does not mean step to the right, it means **turn** the laser right by 90 degrees. The `A` command moves the laser in its current direction of travel. In your code the laser steps to the left and right but otherwise always moves downwards.

Comment: You made a reasonable effort to explain your issue, though its a lot of text to read. What is actually needed is the code ([mcve] I think we have that), example input (its there too) and output and expected output (cannot find that). Everything on top is nice and helps but without a simple statement about the expected output it is difficult to help

Comment: The minimum amount of stuff you need to do to make it work is: https://onlinegdb.com/_5mfi36hB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice task. And well described.

From programing point of view, regarding algorithms and skill the program has a low complexity. The programming effort is high.

But the description gives a lot of detailed requirements and some good hints.

In programming you would now analyze the requirements and then derive a design. After that would implement and test everything.

One of the most important hint in the description is to use multiple functions for solving small pieces of the problem. That is a very important rule that will help you always. Break down the big problem in smaller ones. The solution for those will be much simpler.

Let us look what smaller building blocks we could use.

- Data structure setup
- Matrix initialization
- Read list with commands from file
- Split one command line into command and potential attribute
- Interpret and execute commands
- Draw resulting matrix

A very important requirement is: Stay always within the bounds of the matrix.

We will now implement the requirements step by step.

Definition of the matrix. Requirements say, use a 2d array with dimensions 10x50. The dimension is an important parameter and so we can define it via global constants. In c++ we use for this nowadays compile time constants, which are defined via the `constexpr` keyword. Also, you might be tempted to use C-Style arrays like `char matrix[10][50]`. Nut it is better to use `std::array` from the container library (This is similar to `std::vector`, but its size is static. To abstract the more and make the understanding easier, we will use the `using` or `typedef` statements to create aliases.

```
// Define the size of the matrix
constexpr int NumberOfRows = 10;
constexpr int NumberOfColumns = 50;

// This will be our 2d matrix
using Matrix = std::array<std::array<char, NumberOfColumns>, NumberOfRows>;
// Note , you could also write
// using Matrix = char[NumberOfRows][NumberOfColumns];
```

Now we need something to initialize the matrix or to fill it with a value. The requirement says, fill it with 0es.

This can be done with a simple double nested `for` loop. We create a function, where we can select the “fill-character”, but give it the default value 0, which means “empty”. The function could be implemented like the below:

```
// Indicator for a not processed field
constexpr char ConditionSolid = '\0';
constexpr char ConditionCut = '\1';

// This will set all values in the matrix 
void fillMatrix(Matrix& matrix, const char fillChar = ConditionSolid) {
    for (int row = 0; row < NumberOfRows; ++row) {
        for (int column = 0; column < NumberOfColumns; ++column) {
            matrix[row][column] = fillChar;
        }
    }
}
```

The next functionality that we need is to read the commands from a file. We need to open the file and check, if it could be opened. Then we need to read line by line and store the results. Since we do not know, how many lines are in the file, we need a container that can grow dynamically, so, a `std::vector` and since the commands have a different and maybe unknown length, we will use one command as a string. All this we will abstract again with the ‘using’ declaration. Since the function may fails, we will return a boolean value, with `true` as success. Something like the below:

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Read commands from file
using CommandLine = std::string;
using CommandList = std::vector<CommandLine>;

bool readCommandsFromFile(const std::string& fileName, CommandList& commandList) {
    // Function return value. True is OK, false means error. We assume error in the beginning
    bool result = false;

    // Open the file.
    std::ifstream ifs(fileName);

    // Check, if the file could be opened
    if (ifs) {
        // Ok, now the file is open, we want to read command lines
        CommandLine commandLine{};
        // Read all lines in a loop, until the all data have been read
        while (std::getline(ifs, commandLine)) {
            // Store new, just read line in the command list
            commandList.push_back(commandLine);
        }
        result = true;
    }
    else {
        // The file could not be opened or any other stream error
        std::cout << "Error, cannot open file.";
    }
    return result;
}
```

So, now we have a list with command lines. Those commands shall be later extracted from the line and split into the command a potential attribute. Since there maybe invalid commands in the command line, we will check this and also return a boolean `false` value, in case of a problem.

This function is a little bit length because of many error checks.

```
// Define List with commands (we directly use the define Letters for that)
using Command = char;
using CommandAttribute = int;

constexpr Command CMD_In = 'I';
constexpr Command CMD_Out = 'O';
constexpr Command CMD_TurnRight = 'R';
constexpr Command CMD_TurnLeft = 'L';
constexpr Command CMD_Move = 'A';

bool getCommand(const CommandLine& commandLine, Command& command, CommandAttribute& commandAttribute) {
    // Function return value. True is OK, false means error. We assume OK in the beginning
    bool result = true;

    // Sanity check
    if (commandLine.length() > 0) {
        // check first letter in cammand line
        switch (commandLine[0]) {
        case CMD_In:            // Fallthrough
        case CMD_Out:           // Fallthrough
        case CMD_TurnRight:     // Fallthrough
        case CMD_TurnLeft:
            command = commandLine[0];
            commandAttribute = 0;
            break;
        case CMD_Move:
            // The move command has a parameter, This we need to convert to an integer
            // First we need to check, if a valid integer is given
            // Integer starts at index 2 we allow only for a small number of integers
            bool validInteger = ((commandLine.length()>1) and (commandLine.length()<6));
            for (int i = 2; i < commandLine.length() and validInteger; ++i) {
                if (not std::isdigit(commandLine[i])) {
                    validInteger = false;
                }
            }
            // Ok there was a valid character sequence forming an integer
            if (validInteger) {
                command = commandLine[0];
                commandAttribute = std::stoi(commandLine.substr(1)));
            }
            else {
                // Some wrong data in the command
                command = '\0';
                commandAttribute = 0;
                result = false;
            }
            break;
        default:
            // Unknwon command. Result of function will be false
            command = '\0';
            commandAttribute = 0;
            result = false;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now we need to execute the commands. We start at x and y position 0, and then read the commands. We execute them step by step.

Important is that we do not cross borders. The movement will be done by adding or subtracting values, depending on the current direction.

For the direction we use an integer. Every time when there is a “right” command, we increment the value. With a modulo 4 division we avoid overflows. For “Left”, we decrement by one. Negative values will be compensated by adding 4. In fact, we will always add 4 and then use modulo division to limit the value.

Unfortunately this is rather lengthy

```
// Execute the commands
using Direction = int;
using LaserState = int;
constexpr Direction DirectionNorth = 0;
constexpr Direction DirectionEast = 1;
constexpr Direction DirectionSouth = 2;
constexpr Direction DirectionWest = 3;
constexpr LaserState LaserStateOff = 0;
constexpr LaserState LaserStateOn = 1;

bool execute(const CommandList& commandList, Matrix& matrix) {
    // Function return value. True is OK, false means error. We assume OK in the beginning
    bool result = true;

    // Set initial values
    int currentX = 0;
    int currentY = 0;
    Direction currentdirection = DirectionEast;
    Command command{};
    CommandAttribute commandAttribute{};
    LaserState laserState = LaserStateOff;

    // Execute all commands
    for (const CommandLine& commandLine : commandList) {

        // First, get the command
        if (getCommand(commandLine, command, commandAttribute)) {
            switch (command) {
            case CMD_In:
                laserState = LaserStateOn;
                matrix[currentY][currentX] = ConditionCut;
                break;
            case CMD_Out:
                laserState = LaserStateOff;
                break;
            case CMD_TurnRight:
                ++currentdirection;
                currentdirection = currentdirection % 4;
                break;
            case CMD_TurnLeft:
                --currentdirection;
                currentdirection = (currentdirection + 4) % 4;
                break;
            case CMD_Move:
                // This is a longer story and should probably be put in a function as well
            {

                // Check Laserstate and correspong fillchar
                char fillChar = ConditionSolid;
                if (laserState == LaserStateOn) {
                    fillChar = ConditionCut;
                }
                int endPosition{};

                switch (currentdirection) {
                case DirectionNorth:
                    // Calculate new target position
                    endPosition = currentY - commandAttribute;
                    // Limit to border
                    if (endPosition < 0) endPosition = 0;

                    // Set values
                    for (int i = currentY; (laserState == LaserStateOn) and  i >= endPosition; --i)
                        matrix[i][currentX] = fillChar;
                    currentY = endPosition;
                    break;
                case DirectionSouth:
                    // Calculate new target position
                    endPosition = currentY + commandAttribute;
                    // Limit to border
                    if (endPosition >= NumberOfRows) endPosition = NumberOfRows-1;

                    // Set values
                    for (int i = currentY; (laserState == LaserStateOn) and i <= endPosition; ++i)
                        matrix[i][currentX] = fillChar;
                    currentY = endPosition;
                    break;
                case DirectionWest:
                    // Calculate new target position
                    endPosition = currentX - commandAttribute;
                    // Limit to border
                    if (endPosition < 0) endPosition = 0;

                    // Set values
                    for (int i = currentX; (laserState == LaserStateOn) and i >= endPosition; --i)
                        matrix[currentY][i] = fillChar;
                    currentX = endPosition;
                    break;
                case DirectionEast:
                    // Calculate new target position
                    endPosition = currentX + commandAttribute;
                    // Limit to border
                    if (endPosition >= NumberOfColumns) endPosition = NumberOfColumns - 1;

                    // Set values
                    for (int i = currentX; (laserState == LaserStateOn) and i <= endPosition; ++i)
                        matrix[currentY][i] = fillChar;
                    currentX = endPosition;
                    break;
                }
            }

                break;
            default:
                result = false;
                std::cout << "Internal programming error.";
                break;
            }
        }
        else {
            // Illegal command found
            result = false;
            std::cout << "Encountered an Invalid command. Terminating.";
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The print function is rather simple. No need to show it here.

Function main will then be rather short. Then we can combine everything together:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Define the size of the matrix
constexpr int NumberOfRows = 10;
constexpr int NumberOfColumns = 50;

// This will be our 2d matrix
using Matrix = std::array<std::array<char, NumberOfColumns>, NumberOfRows>;
// Note , you could also write
// using Matrix = char[NumberOfRows][NumberOfColumns];

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Indicator for a not processed field
constexpr char ConditionSolid = '\0';
constexpr char ConditionCut = '\1';

// This will set all values in the matrix 
void fillMatrix(Matrix& matrix, const char fillChar = ConditionSolid) {
    for (int row = 0; row < NumberOfRows; ++row) {
        for (int column = 0; column < NumberOfColumns; ++column) {
            matrix[row][column] = fillChar;
        }
    }
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Read commands from file
using CommandLine = std::string;
using CommandList = std::vector<CommandLine>;

bool readCommandsFromFile(const std::string& fileName, CommandList& commandList) {
    // Function return value. True is OK, false means error. We assume error in the beginning
    bool result = false;

    // Open the file.
    std::ifstream ifs(fileName);

    // Check, if the file could be opened
    if (ifs) {
        // Ok, now the file is open, we want to read command lines
        CommandLine commandLine{};
        // Read all lines in a loop, until the all data have been read
        while (std::getline(ifs, commandLine)) {
            // Store new, just read line in the command list
            commandList.push_back(commandLine);
        }
        result = true;
    }
    else {
        // The file could not be opened or any other stream error
        std::cout << "Error, cannot open file.";
    }
    return result;
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Define List with commands (we directly use the define Letters for that)
using Command = char;
using CommandAttribute = int;

constexpr Command CMD_In = 'I';
constexpr Command CMD_Out = 'O';
constexpr Command CMD_TurnRight = 'R';
constexpr Command CMD_TurnLeft = 'L';
constexpr Command CMD_Move = 'A';

bool getCommand(const CommandLine& commandLine, Command& command, CommandAttribute& commandAttribute) {
    // Function return value. True is OK, false means error. We assume OK in the beginning
    bool result = true;

    // Sanity check
    if (commandLine.length() > 0) {
        // check first letter in cammand line
        switch (commandLine[0]) {
        case CMD_In:            // Fallthrough
        case CMD_Out:           // Fallthrough
        case CMD_TurnRight:     // Fallthrough
        case CMD_TurnLeft:
            command = commandLine[0];
            commandAttribute = 0;
            break;
        case CMD_Move: {
            // The move command has a parameter, This we need to convert to an integer
            // First we need to check, if a valid integer is given
            // Integer starts at index 2 we allow only for a small number of integers
            bool validInteger = ((commandLine.length() > 1) and (commandLine.length() < 6));
            for (int i = 2; i < commandLine.length() and validInteger; ++i) {
                if (not std::isdigit(commandLine[i])) {
                    validInteger = false;
                }
            }
            // Ok there was a valid character sequence forming an integer
            if (validInteger) {
                command = commandLine[0];
                commandAttribute = std::stoi(commandLine.substr(1));
            }
            else {
                // Some wrong data in the command
                command = '\0';
                commandAttribute = 0;
                result = false;
            }}
            break;
        default:
            // Unknwon command. Result of function will be false
            command = '\0';
            commandAttribute = 0;
            result = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Execute the commands
using Direction = int;
using LaserState = int;
constexpr Direction DirectionNorth = 0;
constexpr Direction DirectionEast = 1;
constexpr Direction DirectionSouth = 2;
constexpr Direction DirectionWest = 3;
constexpr LaserState LaserStateOff = 0;
constexpr LaserState LaserStateOn = 1;

bool execute(const CommandList& commandList, Matrix& matrix) {
    // Function return value. True is OK, false means error. We assume OK in the beginning
    bool result = true;

    // Set initial values
    int currentX = 0;
    int currentY = 0;
    Direction currentdirection = DirectionEast;
    Command command{};
    CommandAttribute commandAttribute{};
    LaserState laserState = LaserStateOff;

    // Execute all commands
    for (const CommandLine& commandLine : commandList) {

        // First, get the command
        if (getCommand(commandLine, command, commandAttribute)) {
            switch (command) {
            case CMD_In:
                laserState = LaserStateOn;
                matrix[currentY][currentX] = ConditionCut;
                break;
            case CMD_Out:
                laserState = LaserStateOff;
                break;
            case CMD_TurnRight:
                ++currentdirection;
                currentdirection = currentdirection % 4;
                break;
            case CMD_TurnLeft:
                --currentdirection;
                currentdirection = (currentdirection + 4) % 4;
                break;
            case CMD_Move:
                // This is a longer story and should probably be put in a function as well
            {

                // Check Laserstate and correspong fillchar
                char fillChar = ConditionSolid;
                if (laserState == LaserStateOn) {
                    fillChar = ConditionCut;
                }
                int endPosition{};

                switch (currentdirection) {
                case DirectionNorth:
                    // Calculate new target position
                    endPosition = currentY - commandAttribute;
                    // Limit to border
                    if (endPosition < 0) endPosition = 0;

                    // Set values
                    for (int i = currentY; (laserState == LaserStateOn) and  i >= endPosition; --i)
                        matrix[i][currentX] = fillChar;
                    currentY = endPosition;
                    break;
                case DirectionSouth:
                    // Calculate new target position
                    endPosition = currentY + commandAttribute;
                    // Limit to border
                    if (endPosition >= NumberOfRows) endPosition = NumberOfRows-1;

                    // Set values
                    for (int i = currentY; (laserState == LaserStateOn) and i <= endPosition; ++i)
                        matrix[i][currentX] = fillChar;
                    currentY = endPosition;
                    break;
                case DirectionWest:
                    // Calculate new target position
                    endPosition = currentX - commandAttribute;
                    // Limit to border
                    if (endPosition < 0) endPosition = 0;

                    // Set values
                    for (int i = currentX; (laserState == LaserStateOn) and i >= endPosition; --i)
                        matrix[currentY][i] = fillChar;
                    currentX = endPosition;
                    break;
                case DirectionEast:
                    // Calculate new target position
                    endPosition = currentX + commandAttribute;
                    // Limit to border
                    if (endPosition >= NumberOfColumns) endPosition = NumberOfColumns - 1;

                    // Set values
                    for (int i = currentX; (laserState == LaserStateOn) and i <= endPosition; ++i)
                        matrix[currentY][i] = fillChar;
                    currentX = endPosition;
                    break;
                }
            }

                break;
            default:
                result = false;
                std::cout << "Internal programming error.";
                break;
            }
        }
        else {
            // Illegal command found
            result = false;
            std::cout << "Encountered an Invalid command. Terminating.";
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// printing the matrix
void print(const Matrix& matrix) {
    std::cout << "\n\n";
    for (int row = 0; row < NumberOfRows; ++row) {
        for (int column = 0; column < NumberOfColumns; ++column) {
            std::cout << ((matrix[row][column] == ConditionCut) ? '*' : ' ');
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}

int main() {
    Matrix matrix{};
    fillMatrix(matrix);

    CommandList commandList{};
    const std::string commandFileName = "r:\\laser.txt";
    if (readCommandsFromFile(commandFileName, commandList)) {
        if (execute(commandList, matrix)) {
            print(matrix);
        }
    }
}
```